# Testing if correct mapper is returned

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Hi I am just writting my first unit test and I have a case where I have to test if the correct mapper is returned.

This is my code:

```
public UserPersonalDetailsDTO GetUserPersonalDetails(int personId)
{
   var mapper = ServiceLocator.GetInstance<IMappingService<UserPersonalDetails, UserPersonalDetailsDTO>>();
   var userPersonalDetails = UnitOfWork.PersonData.GetUserPersonalDetails(personId);
   var userPersonalDetailsDTO = mapper.Map(userPersonalDetails);
   return userPersonalDetailsDTO;
}
```

How would I test if I am getting the correct mapper?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I am using Unity as my DI Framework this si my constructor:

```
 public ProfileService(IEConnectUow uow, IValidationService validationService, IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
        : base(uow, serviceLocator)
    {
        m_ValidationService = validationService;
    }
```

My CUrrent class inherits from a BaseCLass that have this properties:

```
protected IEConnectUow UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    protected IServiceLocator ServiceLocator { get; set; }

    public BaseService(IEConnectUow uow, IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    {
        UnitOfWork = uow;
        ServiceLocator = serviceLocator;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is really difficult to unit test.  At least two of the dependencies come in via statics (`ServiceLocator`, `UnitOfWork`).

I would refactor the code to the following

```
public class Whatever {

   private IMappingService<UserPersonDetails, UserPersonalDetailsDTO> mapper;

   private PersonData personData;

   public Whatever(IMappingService<UserPersonDetails, UserPersonalDetailsDTO> mapper, 
                   PersonData personData) {}

   public UserPersonalDetailsDTO GetUserPersonalDetails(int personId) {
       var userPersonalDetails = personData.GetUserPersonalDetails(personId);
       var userPersonalDetailsDTO = mapper.Map(userPersonalDetails);
       return userPersonalDetailsDTO;
   }
}
```

In the whatever class you can now test the interactions with the objects you pass in.  You don't want to be testing that the right mapper is returned in this class.  In a unit test, ideally you only want to test the logic of the class and its interactions with dependencies.  In this case, I'd simply test the interactions.  `GetUserPersonalDetails` talks to the `PersonData` object, and uses the `Mapper` to get the result.

Testing that you get the right mapper isn't the responsibility of this class.  Factor that logic out somewhere (perhaps starting with `ServiceLocator`) into its own class with its own dependencies and verify it does what you want.

Comment: Both ServiceLocator and UnitOfWork are properties defined in a baseclass I just added the code for them

Comment: Fab.  The same points still apply.  Testing you get the right mapper is a property of the service locator class, not of your profile service.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ServiceLocator` is some factory class. If the `ServiceLocator` is writen by you, you can test is seperately. If it is a libary class, the libary is tested (assumue). You can test is the `GetInstance<IMappingService<UserPersonalDetails, UserPersonalDetailsDTO>>();` method is called for the correct types. This can be done with a mocking framework. You make a mock for the `GetInstance` method and then check if it is called, you know the `GetInstance` method is right because you have tested it somewhere else.

My test whould look like (pseudo code):

```
Make mock ServiceLocator.GetInstance
Make mock UnitOfWork.PersonData.GetUserPersonalDetails
Make mock mapper.Map

call GetUserPersonalDetails(int personId)

check if ServiceLocator.GetInstance was correct
```